# Lower bound for the minimum of the maximum frequency of an element - with restrictions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a family $\mathcal{F}$ of non-empty sets, with
$n=|\mathcal{F}|$ sets, $q=\left|\cup\mathcal{F}\right|$ elements in the universe, and $q\le n/4$.

It is known that of the $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose a pair of elements of $\mathcal{F}$, at least $\frac23$ of those ways give a pair with some element in common.

Therefore, if $m$ is minimal such that

$$\binom{m}2 \ge \frac{\frac{2}{3}\binom{n}2}q,$$

then some element belongs to at least $m$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$.

However since those $m$ sets must have more than one element, I think there must also be an element in at least $f(n,q)$ sets with $f(n,q) \gt m$.

How can we calculate or estimate a good value for $f$?

The question is like [this previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/440236/136218) but specifying $r=2/3$ and $q \le n/4$.

Comment: I streamlined this; it'd also be nice to make it self-contained with a link to what "is known".

Comment: @MattF. I think you introduced an error in the definition of $m$.  As such, your inequaility holds more easily for larger $m$.  For example, it clearly holds for $m=n+1$, but there cannot be an element in $n+1$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I reverted it to what I think is intended.